# Is it possible to make acrylic windows like w10 applications using tkinter in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently working on an application using tkinter. It's looking pretty good, but there's one thing missing. I know that it's possible to make the window transparent, but I'm trying to see if we can make it become transparent and blurry like newer windows 10 apps. I've been searching for this for a long time, but I never found the answer. If anyone knows please tell me, help would be gladly appreciated. This is my code so far, it's just a simple random password and number generator: (I also need help for the copyclipboard part of the number generator, it doesn't really work for no reason.)

```
import os
import random
import tkinter
import tkinter as tk
import time

class functions(tk.Frame):
    global passwordgen
    def passwordgen():
        Characters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','@','#','$','*','^','%','(',')','!','~']
        global randomletters
        randomletters=""
        letters=20
        for i in range(letters):
            randomletters=randomletters+random.choice(Characters)
        Passlabel.config(text="Password Generated: " + randomletters)
        print("Password generated: " + randomletters)
        file1 = open("Test3Pass.txt","a") 
        file1.write("Password Generated: " + randomletters + "\n")
        file1.close()

    global quit
    def quit():
        main.destroy()

    global copyclip
    def copyclip():
        try:
            main.clipboard_clear()
            main.clipboard_append(randomletters)
            Passlabel.config(text="Copied password to clipboard!")
            Numlabel.config(text="")
        except:
            print("An error occured while copying the password to the clipboard. Did you generate a password before copying it?")
    
    global copynum
    def copynum():
        try:
            main.clipboard_clear()
            main.clipboard_append(randomnumbers)
            Passlabel.config(text="Copied numbers to clipboard!")
            Numlabel.config(text="")
        except:
            print("An error occured while copying the password to the clipboard. Did you generate a password before copying it?")
    
    global numbergen
    def numbergen():
        Numbs = ['6', '3', '1', '4', '2', '6', '5', '8', '7']
        randomnumbers = ""
        letters=20
        for i in range(letters):
            randomnumbers=randomnumbers+random.choice(Numbs)
        Numlabel.config(text="Numbers Generated: " + randomnumbers)
        print("Numbers Generated: " + randomnumbers)
        file1 = open("Test3Pass.txt","a") 
        file1.write("Numbers Generated: " + randomnumbers + "\n" )
        file1.close()

class app(tk.Frame):
    print("Starting application", end="")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(".", end="")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(".", end="")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(".", end=" ")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Done!")
    global main
    main = tk.Tk()
    main.title("Strong Password Generator")
    main.iconbitmap("transparent.ico")
    main.wait_visibility(main)
    main.update()
    main.wm_attributes('-alpha',0.8)
    main.config(bg="black")
    
class Widgets(tk.Frame):
    global TextLabel
    TextLabel = tk.Label(main, text="Press Generate to generate a 20 character strong password below. Press the Copy button to copy it to your clipboard.\nIt also saves it to a file called Test3Pass.txt, which should be in the same folder as the test3.py.", bg="black", fg="white", font=("Consolas", 8))
    TextLabel.pack()
    global Passlabel
    Passlabel = tk.Label(main, text="", font=("Consolas", 8), bg="black", fg="white")
    Passlabel.pack()
    global Numlabel
    Numlabel = tk.Label(main, text="", font=("Consolas", 8), bg="black", fg="white")
    Numlabel.pack()
    Passgenbtn = tk.Button(main, text="Generate Password", fg="green", bg="black", command=passwordgen)
    Passgenbtn.pack()
    Numbtn = tk.Button(main, text="Generate Numbers", fg="green", bg="black", command=numbergen)
    Numbtn.pack()
    Copybtn = tk.Button(main, text="Copy Password", fg="green", bg="black", command=copyclip)
    Copybtn.pack()
    Copybtn2 = tk.Button(main, text="Copy Numbers", fg="green", bg="black", command=copynum)
    Copybtn2.pack()
    Exitbtn = tk.Button(main, text="      Exit       ", fg="red", bg="black", command=quit)
    Exitbtn.pack()
    main.mainloop()

# also, for the people who want to use my code, you should create a file called test3.txt (in the same directory), so that it can save the passwords or numbers generated inside of it.
```

Comment: Tk isn't cutting edge. It has a notion of [styles](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html) which can try to e.g. emulate the look of Windows apps, although it is unlikely to directly support all the newest eye candy.

Comment: I think I'm going to be sticking with Kivy or PyQt5 for now.